# Google Data Studio - Make COUNT_DISTINCT work on whole data instead of specific category in pie chart

Tags: google-bigquery, data-visualization, pie-chart, looker-studio

Basically, I have a dataset which has four fields: date, userId, distance, and type.​

For example:

| date. | userId | distance | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-09-10 | A | 1200 | foot |
| 2020-09-08 | B | 500 | car |
| 2020-09-08 | A | 400 | car |
| 2020-09-09 | C | 800 | foot |

Now, I'm trying to create a pie chart where the dimension is the type, and the metric is the average distance travelled per user.

So, based on the above, if I'm looking at the period from 2020-09-08 to 2020-09-10,
the average car distance per user should be calculated as `(500+400)/3` (we want to divide by the total number of users and not just the number of users who have actually travelled by car during this period).

I'm trying to achieve this by creating a metric with the following formula:
`SUM(distance)/COUNT_DISTINCT(userId)`

However, what seems to be happening is that since I'm using "type" as the dimension for the pie chart, it's grouping the data, and then applying `COUNT_DISTINCT​`. Since there are only two users who have travelled by car, then `COUNT_DISTINCT(userId)` ​returns 2. So it's calculating the average car distance per user as (500+400)/2 instead of (500/400)/3.

Hope you can help

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blend the data to itself, and set it up like this:

[image]

Then create the pie chart with this formula:

```
sum(distance)/userId
```

Here's the output:

[image]

Comment: Yes that's it! Works perfectly. Thanks so much!

Comment: glad it helped :)